# Cannot refresh page after deleting a row in a grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone see why this code doesn't work?
I know that someone will notice that I am using Delete links and I should be using a DELETE verb rather than a POST, but I have not been able to resolve that issue, even with the help of SO. 
No the issue here is that I click on delete, the underlying data gets deleted OK, but after I delete the data, when I try to redirect to the Payroll GET method, it does not get called and as a result the screen does not get refreshed.
So here is the code on the Controller;

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts, ManagerAccounts")]
public ActionResult Payroll()
{
    if ((SessionObjects.PeriodStartDate > DateTime.MinValue) && (SessionObjects.PeriodEndDate > DateTime.MinValue))
        if (SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId == 0)
            return View(new PayrollViewModel()
                {
                    PeriodStartDate = SessionObjects.PeriodStartDate,
                    PeriodEndDate = SessionObjects.PeriodEndDate
                });
        else
            return View(new PayrollViewModel(
                SessionObjects.PeriodStartDate,
                SessionObjects.PeriodEndDate,
                SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId
                ));

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts, ManagerAccounts")]
public ActionResult Payroll(PayrollViewModel _pvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SessionObjects.PeriodStartDate = _pvm.PeriodStartDate;
        SessionObjects.PeriodEndDate = _pvm.PeriodEndDate;
        if (_pvm.SearchTextId > 0)
            SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId = _pvm.SearchTextId;
        return RedirectToAction("Payroll");
    }
    return View(_pvm);
}

//[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts, ManagerAccounts")]
public RedirectToRouteResult Delete(int id)
{
    EmployeeOtherLeaf.Delete(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Payroll");
}
```

Part of the View and Editor Template;

```
    <table class="groupBorder">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Leave Type</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Day Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Approver</th>
        </tr>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.LeaveList)%>
    </table>

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.WebUI.Models.Leave>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SHP.WebUI.HtmlHelpers" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SHP.Models" %>

<%: Html.RowStyle(Model.RowColour) %>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:White;">
        <%-- Ajax Delete --%>
        <% if(Model.LeaveId > 0) { %>
        <%: Html.DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave()%>
        <%} %>
    </td>
    <td><%: Model.LeaveType %></td>
    <td><%: Model.Notes %></td>
    <td><%: Model.DayAmount %></td>
    <td><%: String.Format("{0:ddd MMM d yyyy}", Model.Date)%></td>
    <td><%: Model.ApproverName %></td>
</tr>
</tbody>    <%-- Leave this here, it closes from the above Html.RowStyle!--%>
```

HTML Helper method;

```
public static MvcHtmlString DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave(this HtmlHelper<Leave> html)
{
    var leave = html.ViewData.Model;
    return html.RouteLink(
        "Delete",
        "Default",
        new {id = leave.LeaveId, action = "Delete" },
        new { onclick = "return DeleteRow(this);" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be invoking the Delete action using AJAX inside the `DeleteRow` javascript function (which you haven't shown). You cannot redirect in AJAX requests. That's the whole point them: do not refresh the entire browser but only portions of it.

If you wanted to perform a full redirect inside the success callback of your AJAX call you could use the `window.location.href` property, like this:

```
success: function(result) {
    window.location.href = '/somecontroller/Payroll';
}
```

Now of course doing something like this is meaningless. I would simply use a standard HTML form which will post top the Delete action and not use any javascript at all:

```
<% if(Model.LeaveId > 0) { %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = leave.LeaveId })) { %>
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Now when the form is submitted the Delete action will be invoked which will perform the actual delete and redirect the browser to the Payroll action => pretty standard HTTP dialogue.

And if you decide to go this way you even get a bonus: you could decorate your controller action with the `[HttpDelete]` attribute and use a technique on the client :

```
<% if(Model.LeaveId > 0) { %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = leave.LeaveId })) { %>
        <%= Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) %>
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

and then:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts, ManagerAccounts")]
public RedirectToRouteResult Delete(int id)
{
    EmployeeOtherLeaf.Delete(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Payroll");
}
```

Under the hood it's not a real DELETE HTTP verb since browsers do not support it for forms but it simulates it using a hidden field which ASP.NET MVC understands and is capable to properly redispatch the request to the corresponding action.

Comment: Spot on. The DELETE verb works this time as well, so even better.